# Is there a way to find the reason for invalid form control in angular 4 reactive forms?

Tags: angular, angular-forms

My form is always becoming invalid even after I fix all the validation errors.

Could you suggest me if there is a way to know which control is still raising the validation error in angular 4 and also the reason for validation error

Comment: Need more info, you could put code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to output your form state in the template using the JSON pipe.

```
<div>
{{ myForm| json }}
</div>
```